# How to run a subscript with variables which are defined in the main script in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a main script which with we will call **main.py**

```
x = 5
import sub.py
```

that I want to use to call a subscript **sub.py** to use the variable I defined in main.py

```
print(x)
```

This gives me an error that x is not defined.

Is there a best practice for effectively 'transitioning' or handing off my variables between scripts? Do I need to define every variable locally, or is there an elegant away to maintain global variables in a given directory that can be recalled across multiple subscripts?

Comment: try `from sub import x`

Comment: @azro, how would that help? The OP is trying to use a variable *from* `main` *in* `sub`, not the other way around.

Comment: @stem__bar, the usual "elegant approach" is to encapsulate those variables in something (a module or other object) that can be passed around. Relying on globals, as in `print(x)`, is generally considered bad code altogether; as opposed to accepting arguments. Even writing a function or object initializer that accepts just a single argument that's one huge object that contains all your variables is better than requiring those variables to be in global scope.

Comment: ...among other arguments, consider ease-of-testing. Much easier to be able to call `runCode(testVarsA)` and then `runCode(testVarsB)` instead of needing to change out a bunch of globals individually between test cases, then clear your import cache and re-import a module over and over between cases. And you can pass around `runCode` and invoke it multiple ways when it's a function or object initializer, whereas it's much more complicated with that with top-level module code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - would it be right to think of a module as a packet that I can generate from one script and then reopen in another script? What file format do these packets usually take (.csv, .txt, .py?)